# Cannot access my localhost from any IP address while localhost and 127.0.0.1 can

Tags: networking, server, apache2, dns, localhost

**I **am very tired because after completing the web application, I can access it through 127.0.0.1 only.
I have a VMware machine with Ubuntu 20.04****

### IP Address

```
ens33: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.123.45  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.123.255
    inet6 fe80::be96:53b2:507b:748a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:0c:29:a1:ff:58  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 30515  bytes 15554369 (15.5 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 22375  bytes 3861844 (3.8 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 5086  bytes 2408659 (2.4 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 5086  bytes 2408659 (2.4 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
lo:0: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.2  netmask 255.0.0.0
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
```

**when i write my localhost in my browser as 192.168.123.45 convert automatically To 127.0.0.1**
and when write my local host as localhost in browser also convert to 127.0.0.1

### my hostes

```
27.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       ubuntu
192.168.123.45       Al-Montazah
```

### Hostname

```
hostname -i
192.168.123.45 fe80::be96:53b2:507b:748a
```

### lsof -n | grep TCP | grep LISTEN##

```
systemd-r  740                 systemd-resolve   13u     IPv4              33405       0t0        TCP 127.0.0.53:domain (LISTEN)
cupsd      774                            root    6u     IPv6              36372       0t0        TCP [::1]:ipp (LISTEN)

cupsd      774                            root    7u     IPv4              36373       0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:ipp (LISTEN)

mysqld     987                           mysql   18u     IPv4              40183       0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:mysql (LISTEN)

mysqld     987 1065 mysqld               mysql   18u     IPv4              40183       0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:mysql (LISTEN)

mysqld     987 1078 mysqld               mysql   18u     IPv4              40183       0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:mysql (LISTEN)

mysqld     987 1085 mysqld               mysql   18u     IPv4              40183       0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:mysql (LISTEN)

mysqld     987 1086 mysqld               mysql   18u     IPv4              40183       0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:mysql (LISTEN)

mysqld     987 1087 mysqld               mysql   18u     IPv4              40183       0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:mysql (LISTEN)

mysqld     987 1088 mysqld               mysql   18u     IPv4              40183       0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:mysql (LISTEN)

mysqld     987 1089 mysqld               mysql   18u     IPv4              40183       0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:mysql (LISTEN)

mysqld     987 1090 mysqld               mysql   18u     IPv4              40183       0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:mysql (LISTEN)

mysqld     987 1091 mysqld               mysql   18u     IPv4              40183       0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:mysql (LISTEN)

mysqld     987 1092 mysqld               mysql   18u     IPv4              40183       0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:mysql (LISTEN)

mysqld     987 1093 mysqld               mysql   18u     IPv4              40183       0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:mysql (LISTEN)

mysqld     987 1094 mysqld               mysql   18u     IPv4              40183       0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:mysql (LISTEN)

mysqld     987 1095 mysqld               mysql   18u     IPv4              40183       0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:mysql (LISTEN)

mysqld     987 1202 mysqld               mysql   18u     IPv4              40183       0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:mysql (LISTEN)

mysqld     987 1203 mysqld               mysql   18u     IPv4              40183       0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:mysql (LISTEN)

mysqld     987 1204 mysqld               mysql   18u     IPv4              40183       0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:mysql (LISTEN)

mysqld     987 1205 mysqld               mysql   18u     IPv4              40183       0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:mysql (LISTEN)

mysqld     987 1206 mysqld               mysql   18u     IPv4              40183       0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:mysql (LISTEN)

mysqld     987 1207 mysqld               mysql   18u     IPv4              40183       0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:mysql (LISTEN)

mysqld     987 1208 mysqld               mysql   18u     IPv4              40183       0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:mysql (LISTEN)

mysqld     987 1209 mysqld               mysql   18u     IPv4              40183       0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:mysql (LISTEN)

mysqld     987 1210 mysqld               mysql   18u     IPv4              40183       0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:mysql (LISTEN)

mysqld     987 1211 mysqld               mysql   18u     IPv4              40183       0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:mysql (LISTEN)

mysqld     987 1212 mysqld               mysql   18u     IPv4              40183       0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:mysql (LISTEN)

mysqld     987 1213 mysqld               mysql   18u     IPv4              40183       0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:mysql (LISTEN)

mysqld     987 1214 mysqld               mysql   18u     IPv4              40183       0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:mysql (LISTEN)

mysqld     987 1215 mysqld               mysql   18u     IPv4              40183       0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:mysql (LISTEN)

mysqld     987 1216 mysqld               mysql   18u     IPv4              40183       0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:mysql (LISTEN)

mysqld     987 1222 mysqld               mysql   18u     IPv4              40183       0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:mysql (LISTEN)

mysqld     987 1251 mysqld               mysql   18u     IPv4              40183       0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:mysql (LISTEN)

mysqld     987 2854 mysqld               mysql   18u     IPv4              40183       0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:mysql (LISTEN)

mysqld     987 2855 mysqld               mysql   18u     IPv4              40183       0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:mysql (LISTEN)

mysqld     987 3295 mysqld               mysql   18u     IPv4              40183       0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:mysql (LISTEN)

mysqld     987 3395 mysqld               mysql   18u     IPv4              40183       0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:mysql (LISTEN)

mysqld     987 3425 mysqld               mysql   18u     IPv4              40183       0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:mysql (LISTEN)

mysqld     987 3426 mysqld               mysql   18u     IPv4              40183       0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:mysql (LISTEN)

apache2   1006                            root    4u     IPv6              38625       0t0        TCP *:http (LISTEN)

apache2   1149                        www-data    4u     IPv6              38625       0t0        TCP *:http (LISTEN)

apache2   1150                        www-data    4u     IPv6              38625       0t0        TCP *:http (LISTEN)

apache2   1151                        www-data    4u     IPv6              38625       0t0        TCP *:http (LISTEN)

apache2   1152                        www-data    4u     IPv6              38625       0t0        TCP *:http (LISTEN)

apache2   1153                        www-data    4u     IPv6              38625       0t0        TCP *:http (LISTEN)

apache2   2539                        www-data    4u     IPv6              38625       0t0        TCP *:http (LISTEN)

apache2   2858                        www-data    4u     IPv6              38625       0t0        TCP *:http (LISTEN)

apache2   4853                        www-data    4u     IPv6              38625       0t0        TCP *:http (LISTEN)

apache2   4873                        www-data    4u     IPv6              38625       0t0        TCP *:http (LISTEN)

apache2   4874                        www-data    4u     IPv6              38625       0t0        TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

i can't access my local host from any ip adress or another computer on the same network
what can i do ?
thank you

Comment: You say "I have a VMware machine with Ubuntu 20.04". What is your hosts ip address, and is it the same sub-net? i.e. is it 192.168.123.YYY?

Comment: my host ip address 192.168.123.45 but it loop to 127.0.0.1 automatically

Comment: and yes the same sub net mask

Comment: Well then what is the IP address of your VM (Virtual Machine)? With my questions, I am wondering if you need to port forward from your host computer to your VM computer. If they are on the same sub-net you don't have to, but if they are on different sub-nets you do.

Answer (score 1):

Your `/etc/hosts` file is wrong. You have both `127.0.0.1` and `192.168.123.45` specified as `localhost`, so the resolver thinks they are the same and replaces one with the other.

If you want the two addresses to be distinguished, write `192.168.123.45` as another hostname. Your machine probably has some "real" hostname (what does `hostname` without `-i` parameter return?), assign that name to `192.168.123.45` instead of `localhost`.

Comment: hostname
Al-Montazah

i edit it now and the same problem still right now 
, its loop again to 127.0.0.1

Comment: @karimkhamiss nuke your browser cache first.  Then try again.  Browsers are notorious for caching things.

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit your mysqld.cnf file, probably located in /etc/mysql/mysql.d/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf (yeah, 4times mysql).

In the line, containing bind-address, change

> bind-address    = 127.0.0.1

to

> bind-address    = 127.0.0.1,192.168.123.45

(You might use the symbolic name as well in the mysqld.cnf - file).

> bind-address    = 127.0.0.1,Al-Montazah

Don't oversee the d in the filename, it stands for daemon (the server).

Then you have to restart the server, for the changes to take effect.

And probably you have to grant permissions in the database to the user, who logs in, which is normally restricted to localhost, without that restriction (@'localhost').